# Optaplanner: how to debug with Logback?

Tags: debugging, logback, slf4j, optaplanner

I am working on a Project with Optaplanner and I am trying to debug the solver. I have looked at this link for the configuration https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/02/23/HowFastIsLogging.html.
All dependencies seem to be added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
       <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.28</version>
    </dependency>
```

The logback.xml is configured as stated in the above link:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.optaplanner" level="debug"/>
  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="appender"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

And the code is compiling, but there is no debugging information on my console. Maybe I am skipping some steps in the logback configuration(?) I am relatively new to programming so anything you find obvious I migth have skipped.

Comment: IIRC there's a enviromnent property for logback or slf4j to spit out where it's getting it's information from. Also, are you mixing this with Quarkus or Spring Boot by any chance?

Comment: Do an "mvn dependency:tree" comparison with optaplanner-examples. That has a logback.xml file and that one does work.